# Rejoining Split MapReduce Arrays in Mongo

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm just learning mapReduce.  I have the following map reduce function being called on a collection of users.

```
function () {

    m = function () {
            emit(this.city, {num:1, arr:this});
    }

    r = function (key, arr_values) {
            var resultArray = [];
            var count = 0;
            arr_values.forEach(function (value) {
                                    resultArray.push(value);
                                    count++;
                                });
            return {num:count, arr:resultArray};
    }

    res = db.AdsOnPage.mapReduce(m, r, {out:"ReducedCollection"});


}
```

This ends up giving me what I need -- "city" as a key, and then an array of the users in that city as the value.  But it's actually giving it to me in an absurd number of nested arrays.  I assume this happens as a result of sharding?  But how do I rejoin everything?  Right now, the results look something like this:

```
{
  "city":"Chicago",
  "value" : {
    "num" : 2.0,
    "arr" : [{
        "num" : 2.0,
        "arr" : [{
            "num" : 1.0,
            "arr" : [{
                <user doc is here>
              }]
          }, {
            "num" : 1.0,
            "arr" : [{
                <user doc is here>
              }]
          }]
      }
.......
for many many arrays
```

Why is this happening?  Is there any way to rejoin my results into a coherent single array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with sharding, this has to with Map / Reduce logic.

The `value` from the `map` function needs to have the same shape as the return from `reduce`.

Remember that the `reduce` can be run multiple times. In fact, in the case of sharding, it will be run once for each shard and then again by the `mongos` making the request.

You're thinking about what happens when you run

`reduce(key, [a,b,c])`

For Map / Reduce to work, the output must be the same as the following:

`reduce(key, [a, reduce(key, [b,c]) )` OR

`reduce(key, [reduce(key, [a,b]), c] )`

In your case `reduce(key, [b,c])` is returning an array so you get the following:

`reduce(key, [a, reduce(key, [b,c]) )` => `reduce(key, [a, [b,c] ])`

Notice the extra array? That's why you are getting nesting.

Solving this problem needs to two parts.

1. If `values` is going to be an array, then `emit` should output an array with one item in it.
2. When you make this change `arr_values` will be an "array of arrays". You will have to combine them correctly.

Hopefully, that points you in the correct direction. For more detailed methods of debugging you may want to look at the page on [Troubleshooting M/R](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Troubleshooting+MapReduce).

Comment: Thanks, @Gates.  But I guess the real problem is the fact that even after solving the nesting, my results are being returned split into multiple arrays.  You say to "combine them correctly." How would I do that?

Comment: In the `reduce` method the `arr_values` is an array of values. Each value is itself an array. So you cannot do `resultArray.push(value);`, that `value` you are pushing is an array. So you'll need another loop inside of the `reduce` that loops through each value.

Answer (score 0):

I use array function Array.isArray(param) and indexOf(param) to solve this kind of problem, but I push unique element in my stack array.

```
if(Array.isArray(param)) {
    for(var i in param) {
       if(stack.indexOf(param[i]) == -1)
           arr.push(param[i]) ;
    }
}
else {
    if(stack.indexOf(param) == -1)
        arr.push(param) ;
}
```

you can make a try Array.isArray().